# Unexpected Dual Lambdas deployed in Serverless Framework Services pattern

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm attempting the [serverless Services](https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-architecture-code-patterns) pattern, with the intention of having a single entrypoint for a couple or three API calls that all relate to the same overall service.  It seems to me that I've followed the suggested pattern, and in fact the code works fine, but I'm seeing ***two*** lambda functions deployed instead of the single function I expect.

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

- The intended handler that will field requests to the desired function is called `router`
- The router exports the two supported functions (`search` and `read`)
- `search` and `read` are implemented in helper functions.  FWIW there are multiple helpers with different implementations of `search` and `read`, driven off a query parm

It all works fine, but as noted, there are two lambdas deployed instead of the desired single lambda, each with a router, each with helpers.  Somehow the API part is seeing each function as entirely separate, even though they reference the same `router` function as entrypoint.

The serverless.yml which should mirror the one in the article, looks like this:

```
functions:
  search:
    handler: router.search
    events:
      - http:
          path: /stuff/search/{site}
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              ...
  read:
    handler: router.read
    events:
      - http:
          path: /stuff/read/{site}
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              ...
```

On deployment I see something like:

```
endpoints:
  GET - https://specificURL.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/search/{site}
  GET - https://specificURL.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/read/{site}
functions:
  search: myproject-dev-search
  read: myproject-dev-read
```

where `specificURL` is the same in each case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every item listed in the `functions` block is a separate lambda function. The example post you cited lays that out somewhat implicitly.

If you'd like to combine the `search` and `read` APIs into the same function, you'll need to perform routing internally. You can do that with several popular frameworks including Express, http-api, or you can build your own.

Then you'll simply proxy all requests to it:

```
functions:
  # REST API
  api:
    handler: index.api
    events:
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
```

Comment: Many thanks ... now that I've looked up the proxy+ capability of Lambda it all comes clear.  Took awhile to realize I had to give up the lovely syntactic sugar that `serverless` supplies with the microservices pattern, but so be it.

Spent more time than I should've looking for a good router library ... lots of great candidates with severe documentation limits so finally found it easiest to write my own.

Which is too bad .. modofun looks exactly what one needs ... but the documentation is so oriented to webserver implementations that it wasn't possible to implement it for Lambda in time

Comment: If you're building a node app, I'd suggest [lambda-api](https://github.com/jeremydaly/lambda-api) as a starting point.

As a word of caution - serverless applications favor microprocess architectures, and not microservices. Microservices don't translate well to serverless